# What are all the possible transitions between matchstick numbers?

Tags: matches

If these are all the matchstick numbers:

```
 _        _   _         _    _    _    _    _
| |   |   _|  _|  |_|  |_   |_     |  |_|  |_|
|_|   |  |_   _|    |   _|  |_|    |  |_|   _|
```

What's the minimum moves (including deletion but not addition) to go between two different digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full table of moves needed  (including deletion but not addition) to go between two different digits

| Number 1 v/Number 2 > | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 0 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | N/A | 1 |
| **1** | N/A | 0 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| **2** | N/A | 4 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 | N/A | 3 | N/A | N/A |
| **3** | N/A | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | N/A | 2 | N/A | N/A |
| **4** | N/A | 2 | N/A | N/A | 0 | N/A | N/A | 2 | N/A | N/A |
| **5** | N/A | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | N/A | 3 | N/A | N/A |
| **6** | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4 | N/A | 1 |
| **7** | N/A | 1 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | 0 | N/A | N/A |
| **8** | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| **9** | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | N/A | 0 |

(Adapted from a [codegolf.stackexchange post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242886/how-many-matchstick-moves-to-change-a-number))